# Excel how to distribute 2 percentage fields between 3 fields

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I'm having a difficulty to figure out how to distribute 2 percentages fields in 3.
Let's say we have 2 teams. I think they both have chances 50/50 means that the draw has the percent of 50, 25 for the first team and 25 for the second team. So i'm stuck in finding the formula to calculate Draw chances.
Another example, if i believe that first team win percent is 70% and second team win is 30%. What would be the % for the draw?

I have tried to divide each team % by 3 and multiply by 2, then deduct sum of these results from 100%, but obviously, in every case I get 33% for the draw. For example I get 33% for the draw in case if chances of both teams are 50/50, instead of 50 for the draw, 25 for first team and 25 for the second team.

Thank you!

Comment: imho, the question seems to be better suited here > https://stats.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Resolved as indicated in this thread: [https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/503614/excel-how-to-distribute-2-percentage-fields-between-3-fields](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/503614/excel-how-to-distribute-2-percentage-fields-between-3-fields)

Comment: glad to hear it was solved..

Comment: Resolved as indicated in this thread: https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/503614/excel-how-to-distribute-2-percentage-fields-between-3-fields